# Can Blender export to the COLLADA format?

Tags: export, collada

Can Blender export to the COLLADA format?

I tried going to `File → Export`, but COLLADA was not an option.

I'm using Blender 2.66.1 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Interesting. Should be there. It's the first option for me. Blender 2.67a

Comment: Can you try this on the latest version and update your answer? Where did you install Blender from? The Irie PPA?

Comment: Yes, it can. Make sure you're using blender official from http://blender.org

Comment: Are you sure that you went to the 'export' menu and not 'save as'? I also saw "Collada (Default) (.dae)" as my first option. Blender 2.66a

Comment: As @aditia mentions, official builds (http://www.blender.org) have COLLADA option enabled by default. If you get builds from other locations (apt sources, graphicall.org, other linux distros) you might get one that doesn't have it turned on.

Comment: collada is a build-option, unofficial builds may disable it.

Comment: FYI: I also have blender 2.66 from the ubuntu repositories and it does not have the collada exporter. I will try irie's PPA

Comment: Debian's blender is built without COLLADA support, there's an old bug/whish but guess didn't gone far, in 2.71 still miss, that's annoying because seem the standard to export to three.js [#694879](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=694879)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use Blender builds from the [irie PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eirie/+archive/blender), and I have it by default:

[image]

#### Installing from the PPA:

- Add the PPA: `ppa:irie/blender` (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender`)
- Update your sources (Ubuntu Software Center does this automatically, but you will need to do it manually if adding from the command line). (`sudo apt-get update`)
- Install `blender` (this package is 2.6x from git) (`sudo apt-get install blender`)

More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa

---

Collada support is enabled and available in these builds.

Comment: Thank you! I was using the default provided in the Ubuntu Software Center. With the version from the irie PPA, everything works.

Comment: I wasn't sure you wanted commandline stuff, but I see you added it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Your build probably wasn't compiled with COLLADA support, otherwise it should be there. Make sure you download an official release from the official site.

Answer (score 3):

Collada file export should come with Blender 2.66a. However, if it isn't installed, there are a number of external plug-ins you can use to get full-featured Collada compatibility.

The best one of these you can download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/colladablender/.

If that doesn't work for you, you can always try exporting to one of the other file type options, and then using an external program to import/convert into a Collada file.

====

Please note: the above link points to a blender 2.49 script. it will not work with recent Blender versions!