# How do I add the ability to import Collada files to Blender 2.76?

Tags: import, collada

[image: No option for Collada]

As you can see from this screenshot, there's no option to import Collada files. There IS such an option in this question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/how-do-i-get-blender-to-import-a-collada-file). Was this removed at some point? Is it not available on the Linux version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Blender export to the COLLADA format?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160/can-blender-export-to-the-collada-format)

Comment: How are you installing blender? The collada import-export  should be part of the default options.

Comment: I'm installing via apt-get, tried using the PPA in the previous answer but it gave me 'This PPA does not support xenial' as an error.

Comment: @AndrewPampuch download and install blender directly from blender.org. I don't know how the distributions for ppa are made, but in my experience they are never the latest version and open the door for this kind of inconsistencies. I'm running blender perfectly on Linux mint, I never use apt-get to install newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

My deleted earlier answer failed to take into account the fact that you are working from a Linux (apparently Debian) distribution. My frame of reference is on Windows, where the ability to import and export Collada files has been part of the default distribution since at least version 2.63, but I don't know that this is true with the versions for distributed by, or for, Debian.

I note in your comment to your question an error message "This PPA does not support xenial"; a quick search of the web shows that the name "xenial" is associated with an Ubuntu Linux distribution, though I'm not sure how this affects your situation.

If I were in your positon, I would first check with the appropriate individuals to see if the capability is been disabled in the Debian distro; if it is, then I would try uninstalling, and reinstalling Blender. If the capability is not part of the Debian version, there is an addon for Blender to import and export Collada files on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/colladablender/), but I have no information as to how well it works, especially under Linux. Otherwise, if you have the skillset, you might try downloading the tarball for Blender directly from the [Blender.org site](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/) and try to install Blender from there, though if you do that much work, you might as well upgrade to 2.77a.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xubuntu 16.04 and this repository install Blender version 2.79a with the Collada import and export options included.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt update && sudo apt install blender
```